# Weird behavior with numpy arrays of arrays in typing

Tags: python, numpy

Why is the first array being converted entirely to string type, while the individual types of the second array remain the same? How would I force the first array (`np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])])`) to consist of a `dtype = np.int64` array and a `dtype = np.str_` array? I tried setting `dtype = object` for the entire array, but this caused the dtypes of the individual arrays to also change to object.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])])
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['a', 'bb', 'ccc']],
      dtype='<U21')
>>> np.array([np.array([1,2,3, 4]), np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])])
array([array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'],
      dtype='<U3')], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.array` sometimes tries to be 'too smart'.  But the basic principle is that it tries to create the highest dimensional array that can with the input.  Only when it fails does it resort to making a simpler array of dtype=object.  Remember, the original intent was to produce a multidimensional array of numbers.  `object` dtype is a more recent, and poorly developed, generalization.

With

```
np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])])
```

the subarrays have the same length.  So it creates the same sort of array as it would if give a list of lists, `np.array([[1,2,3],["a", "bb", "ccc"]])`.  And since it can't force "a" to be an int, it forces `1` to be a string.  I'm not sure why it gave you a `U21` and me `U11`.  Seems that `U3` would have been sufficient.

Another way to think of this, is `concatenate` on a new axis.  Recent versions added a `np.stack` that gives more control over that.

```
np.stack([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])])
```

But in the 2nd case, the 2 arrays have different length.  It can't form a 2d array from those, so it leaves them as is, and makes a 1d 2element object array.

There are a couple of tricks that can be used to make an object array with equal length elements.  One is make an empty object array of the right size, and assign the elements

```
In [81]: x=np.empty((2,), dtype=object)
In [82]: x[:] = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])]
In [83]: x
Out[83]: 
array([array([1, 2, 3]), array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], 
      dtype='<U3')], dtype=object)
```

Another is to start with elements of different size, and change or delete one.

```
In [84]: x = np.array([[1,2,3,4], ["a", "bb", "ccc"]])
In [85]: x[0] = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if the sub-arrays have compatible shapes, numpy creates an extra dimension for their shared shape.  This is the case in your first example, and if you check the `shape` of that object you will see it is `(2, 3)`.  In your second example the sub-array shapes cannot be reconciled so you get a 1D array of shape `(2,)`.

As far as I know there is no way to force `nd.array` to create the array as dtype object without propagating that change to the sub-arrays.  It is a somewhat strange thing to want, since most of the benefits of numpy arrays will be limited or eliminated.  You can do it by, for instance, pre-creating the array and populating it afterwards:

```
x = np.zeros((2,), dtype=object)
x[0] = np.array([1,2,3])
x[1] = np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])

>>> x
array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([u'a', u'bb', u'ccc'], 
      dtype='<U3')], dtype=object)
>>> x[0].dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> x[1].dtype
dtype('<U3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the outputs:

```
>>> np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])])
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['a', 'bb', 'ccc']],
      dtype='<U11')

>>> np.array([np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])])
array([array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'],
      dtype='<U3')], dtype=object)
```

The first output concatenates the arrays into a 2x1 array, each cell with three elements. The second output does not concatenate the arrays.

Now, watch this:

```
>>> a = np.array([np.array([1,2,3])])
>>> b = np.array([np.array(['i','j','k'])])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b))
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['i', 'j', 'k']],
      dtype='<U11')

>>> a = np.array([np.array([1,2,3,4])])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

>>> np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
array([['1', '2', '3', '4', 'i', 'j', 'k']],
      dtype='<U11')
```

See the difference? When Numpy tries to concatenate arrays of ints and strings, if they each have the same dimension, NumPy will convert the ints to strings. If they don't have equal dimensions, it won't concatenate them because you get those errors.